# Public IP address hides device from network

Tags: networking, ssh, dhcp, ip

I have flashed a mini-image of Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS onto my
[BeagleBone Black](http://beagleboard.org/BLACK). (Find latest [*BBB image*](http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack_Debian#Flashing_eMMC)).

The BBB is connected to my home Router via Cat5 **AND** USB cables. Understandably, I can directly SSH into the device over the Ethernet interface using the device's DHCP address (i.e. 10.0.0.X/8).

However, once I configure my router to assign my BBB the Public IPv4 address (i.e. 120.40.x.x), the BBB *disappears* from the network. Unfortunately, this problem does NOT  reproduce when assigning the IP to a different machine. Please note, all of my computers utilize the DHCP service for receiving their own IP address.

For trouble shooting, I removed the `usb0` interface from the BBB's `/etc/network/interfaces` file and confirmed via `ifconfig` that it was so. Furthermore, I installed network-manager and restarted the service, as well as all devices.

Finally ... The BBB only reappears when the public IP address assignment is removed, or if the public IP address is reassigned to a different device. Meaning to say, it receives a 10.0.0.x address once again.

Although my question is very network themed, I think my problem is more likely solved in some other network configuration file instead. Belivably, it stems from the combination of using a mini-ubuntu version, as well as a preconfigured image from somebody else.

If somebody could assist me with coming to the solution, it will be very much appreciated.

**Edit:**
[image: Diagram of my network]

Comment: When you say it disappears from the network, what specifically stops working? Are you saying that it no longer has a 10.0.0.x on your LAN, or just that it is no longer visible from some application running on another computer?

How are you expecting the BBB to fit into your network? If you are assigning it your public IP address, it can't be on your LAN anymore since it will be directly connected to the Internet, unless it has a second interface. What are you trying to do with the USB interface? What are you trying to do with it in general?

Comment: It's definitely a routing issue.  Can you draw up a diagram on how your network is set up, because changing an IP address from 10.x.y.z to anything else *is supposed to make it disappear* from the 10.x.y.z. network, so I want to understand why your other machines don't (might be that they still connect using the IPV6 stack or so which the BBB doesn't have or something similar)

Comment: @Omegamormegil the USB connection is purely for powering the device, and please see my newly uploaded network-diagram that should answer your other questions.

Comment: What application is that a screenshot of

Comment: Good question, its just the default firmware application that runs on the router for me to look at. My Router product name is: TG797n v3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To establish a successful connection I had to switch `[ifupdown] managed` to 'true', even though all my other machines had very similar configuration settings.

To quote the NetworkManager manual:

> If set to true, then interfaces listed in /etc/network/interfaces are
>   managed by NetworkManager. If set to false, then any interface listed
>   in /etc/network/interfaces will be ignored by NetworkManager. Remember
>   that NetworkManager controls the default route, so because the
>   interface is ignored, NetworkManager may assign the default route to
>   some other interface.
>
> The default value is false.

And for reference, find the property at: `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

(if absent, *apt-get install network-manager*, then *sudo service network-manager restart*).